# How can I use goquery parse single element

Tags: go, ssml, goquery

```html
<speak><voice name=\"en-US-JennyNeural\"><prosody rate=\"1\">aaaaaaaa<break time=\"5s\"/> bbbb. <br time=\"2s\"/>ccccccdddddddd </prosody></voice></speak>
```

I use this code to parse and get:

```golang
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(text))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    ssml, err := doc.Find("html body").Html()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
```

Result:

```html
<speak><voice name="en-US-JennyNeural"><prosody rate="1">aaaaaaaa<break time="5s"> bbbb. <br time="2s"/>ccccccdddddddd </break></prosody></voice></speak>
```

I think the break doesn't parse Correctly. I want to parse `<break/>` like `<br/>`.

Comment: The text about text to speak ssml, I want to decode.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [`github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery), it uses [`golang.org/x/net/html`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html) under the hood for HTML parsing, which is an HTML5-compliant tokenizer and parser.

`<br>` and `<break>` are parsed differently because in HTML `<br>` is a tag that must not have a closing tag, but `<break>` is not such a tag.

If you want `goquery` to handle your HTML properly, you must use an explicit closing tag for `<break>` instead of the self-closing tag.

E.g. instead of this:

```
<break time="5s"/>
```

You must use this:

```
<break time="5s"></break>
```

With this change your output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/6f5bet55_kX)):

```
<speak><voice name="en-US-JennyNeural"><prosody rate="1">aaaaaaaa<break time="5s"></break> bbbb. <br time="2s"/>ccccccdddddddd </prosody></voice></speak>
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
Do you know what go package can easily analyze the above ssml?

Comment: I don't. Try asking from google.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
    d := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(text))
    var writer bytes.Buffer
    e := xml.NewEncoder(&writer)
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        if t == nil {
            break
        }
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            e.EncodeToken(se)

        case xml.EndElement, xml.CharData, xml.Comment, xml.ProcInst, xml.Directive:
            e.EncodeToken(se)
        }
    }
    e.Flush()

    return writer.String(), nil
```